# Why is context different in these two event handlers

Tags: javascript, this

This is a basics question but I cannot figure out why the context (`this`) is correct in the second event handler and incorrect in the first one.

I have this simple constructor function to create the object `myNotifier`:

```
function Notifier ( message ) {
  this.message = message;
  this.saySomething = function () {
    alert( "I say:" + this.message);
  }
}
   
myNotifier = new Notifier(" HELLO!");
```

Then I use the `myNotifier.saySomething()` method as an event handler for CLICK on two buttons:

```
$(".button1").click( myNotifier.saySomething );
$(".button2").click( function () { myNotifier.saySomething()});
```

The first one shows:  "I say: undefined"
The second one shows: "I say: HELLO"

I understand that the context (`this`) is not the original object when calling the method, but why is it correct when calling inside a function for the second button?

A [jsfiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/pablol/m7Hb6/)

Comment: I'm so glad you are trying to work this fundamental of javascript OO. In jQuery despite being quite confusing the jQuery.proxy() function will allow you to do the following
$(".button1").click(jQuery.proxy(myNotifier, 'saySomething'));
or 
$(".button1").click(jQuery.proxy(myNotifier.saySomething , myNotifier));
I said confusing because you can pass the context "myNotifier" and the  function name as a string "saySomething" but you can also pass the function reference and the context. I still wonder to this day why the function signature mutate that way, it just do make any sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [MDN's reference for the `this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this): Yes, the context depends on the way you call the method.

If you call the function as a property of an object (like in the handler for button2), that object will be used as the context.

However, if you use it as an event handler (it's the same if wrapped by jQuery), the context of calling the function is the current DOM element, to which the listener is bound. And the button has no property "message", so it will alert `undefined`.

Of course, those are not the only alternatives; you might try

```
var fn = myNotifier.saySomething;
fn(); // context is the global object (window)
```

or

```
myNotifier.saySomething.call({message:"buh!"});
```

:-) - see MDN for explanation and more.

Answer (score 1):

for `$(".button1").click` the `this` keyword is the Dom element with the class `button1`.

for `$(".button2")` the `this` keyword refers to the anonymous function in which you wrapped the call to `myNotifier.saySomething()`

You can change the context of the function by using the [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) prototype function.

Comment: Nope for $(".button2") the this keyword refer to the instance "myNotifier" of the function constructor "Notifier" and the anonymous function only allow you to create a closure of the instance "myNotifier" by calling one of his method within the context of the instance.