# Undefined variable in keypress event

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have this code in my project, that uses Prototype 1.7.1

```
var Worker = Class.create({
    initialize: function() {
        this.ap = $('ap');

        alert( this.ap.value );

        $( 'main-form' ).on( 'change', '.inputs', this.recount );
        this.ap.observe( 'keypress', this.recount );
    },
    recount: function() {
        alert( this.ap.value );
    }
});
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
    var w = new Worker();
});
```

Item of `id="ap"` is text input field inside a form. Inside above class initializer, `#ap` element is found, `this.ap` member is assigned ( alert shows correct value ).

Now, when I change `#ap` input value, `recount` method called by `keypress` event gives me an error - `this.ap` is undefined. After I click outside of this input, to loose focus, `recount` method called by `change` event works correctly ( `this.ap` is assigned ).

Comment: What is the question? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546174/why-is-context-different-in-these-two-event-handlers... different library, same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the handler will be executed in context of the DOM element - `this` does not point to your `Worker` instance. Use

```
$( 'main-form' ).on( 'change', '.inputs', this.recount.bind(this) );
```

Btw, it is not a good idea to name your class "Worker" - this would overwrite the global WebWorker constructor.

Comment: ok, the `.bind(this)` part works ;) however, it was the second event that was the problem, so the correct solution is: `this.ap.observe( 'keypress', this.recount.bind(this) );`

anyway thanks ^_^

P.S.
class renamed